# Rounding function issue

Tags: python

I am learning Python currently and working on writing a little program given as a task from the book I am working through. I am working with the `round()` function and for the most part it is working. One line isn't though and I can't for the life of me figure it out. Any help is appreciated. The portion that isn't working is:

```
billtip1 = bill + tip1
round(billtip1, 2)
```

Towards the end of this section of code:

```
bill = input("\nEnter in the bill total: $ ")
bill = float(bill)

tip1 = bill * .15
tip2 = bill * .20

tip1 = round(tip1, 2)
tip2 = round(tip2, 2)

print("\nA 15% tip would be: ", tip1)
print("\nA 20% tip would be: ", tip2)

billtip1 = bill + tip1
round(billtip1, 2)

billtip2 = bill + tip2
round(billtip2, 2)

print("\nTotal bill with 15% tip:$ ", billtip1)
print("\nTotal bill with 20% tip:$ ", billtip2)
```

Answer (score 3):

The round `builtin` function returns a value.  Therefore, you have to assign the result to a variable.

For example, 
*`variable = round(number[, ndigits])`*

In your case:

```
billtip1 = round(bill + tip1, 2)
billtip2 = round(bill + tip2, 2)
```

To view more about round, see [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html)

Answer (score 1):

`round` doesn't do anything unless you assign the result to something. Try:

```
billtip1 = bill + tip1
billtip1 = round(billtip1, 2)

billtip2 = bill + tip2
billtip2 = round(billtip2, 2)
```

Comment: This was it. Thank you for the quick response.